# Replace image field content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type with image field and need to replace it with another image already uploaded on server. Best would be to do it with AJAX call to avoid page reload. 
Is it just a matter of replacing "fid" in node's field value?

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing with the ajax framework lately myself. There are probably better approaches, but the difficulty is in placing multiple ajax events on a single form element and file fields already have one on them.

One option could be to implement [hook_ajax_render_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/7), and add to/modify/replace what  file_ajax_upload() provided in the $commands array as needed..

Comment: Thanks @johnbburg but I don't want to modify image during upload but later on after initial image is uploaded.